# Build Xamarin.Android doesn't work with AOT

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I created new project xamarin forms protable. 
I didn't add other code in projects.

When I build Android project with AOT options I get error:

```
[AOT] E:\works\xamarin\projects\TestAot\TestAot\TestAot.Droid\obj\Release\android\assets\TestAot.Droid.dll
Could not AOT the assembly: obj\Release\android\assets\TestAot.Droid.dll
```

Xamarin.VS and Android SDK updated to last versions.

How fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45173

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, I saw it and i added comment to this ticket

Answer (score 4):

Faced that if you enable llvm along with aot, it just gives you the above error. Some say it happens when you are compiling on a 64-bit windows, while compiling in cloud works fine. Anyway there's a solution, basically disabling the 'embedassembliesintoapk':

[image]

The above settings work fine for me.

Consider that aot+llvm can have an app startup time longer than with aot alone.

Credits: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/302015/#Comment_302015

Answer (score 0):

AOT is still experimental by nature. Thus results may turn out to be unstable or in an unworking state.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#AOT_Support

> AOT and AOT+LLVM support has always been experimental. It has been discovered that AOT+LLVM support hasn't worked since at least Xamarin.Android 6.0; the AOT+LLVM compiler executed but didn't do anything. During QA, it was determined that in attempting to fix the "AOT+LLVM didn't do anything" issue, the AOT+LLVM compiler instead crashed.
>
> Consequently, AOT+LLVM support has been disabled in the Xamarin.Android 6.1 release. It will be re-enabled in a future release.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_6/xamarin.android_6.1/

Comment: As Jon points out, AOTing Android assemblies can be "dodgy", I would recommend making sure you are on the ***latest*** version as Android Mono AOT bugs are being fixed in just about every release. A HelloWorld app should AOT and run OK. I updated to  `Xamarin.Android` v7.0.2.37 and patched it with the new `AndroidAotAdditionalArguments` feature and I have one app that runs great and is wicked fast, one that fails (and has always runtime failed with AOT) and one that fails on only one method (that I moved to a separate assembly and the build scripts removes that assembly's AOT'd `.so` file.

Comment: @SushiHangover I upgrade to Xamarin.Android v7.0.2.37 and Xamarin.VS v4.2.1.52 (beta chanel) but I get still "Could not AOT the assembly". 
What do I do?

Comment: @user1658602 The answer is to not use AOT at this time as it is not production ready.

Comment: @JonDouglas It's a pity. AOT gave fast start and best performance

Comment: @user1658602 I do not normally use Forms for production work, but I just tried `Xamarin.Forms` 2.3.2.127 w/ `Xamarin.Android` 7.0.2.37, edited the Android `.csproj` with `AotAssemblies` for the `Release` configuration and compiled/run fine... But as Jon says it is not "production" quality and has always been listed as experimental. I've been using Mono AOT'd and LLVM'd code for **many** years and for some numerical/computation intensive apps I put up with the issues as I know how to work around them and even have custom-written LLVM optimizers for it, for clients I steer them away from it.

Comment: @SushiHangover Do you only compile project or Archive also? This problem be only in Archive process

Comment: @user1658602 I "archive for publishing" also; signed and packaged Release-based `.apk`s...

Comment: @SushiHangover Hmm. I and several people has same problem. it's queerly.

Comment: @SushiHangover P.S. Maybe, do you use Xamarin Studio? So it works for you.

Comment: @user1658602 Using Windows/VS and macOS/XS... :-/

Comment: @SushiHangover And AOT worked in VS? If it is true that I don't know how to fix this problem