# Xamarin Forms Android: Getting XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, aot

Getting error on almost all assemblies (list bellow) no matter linker option. I don't figure out where is the problem with the AOT compiler. Do you have an idea?

**EDIT:** I am a newbie on xamarin and app development. 
Full error message with diagnostic level [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ONoB31fijX6rOjD5CWtZqp652n65CRdR/view?usp=sharing). Sample project reproducting the issue [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyvmzTdgCLLiH1McmNTsDI-TklOTJZ4q/view?usp=sharing).

**Assemblies impacted:**

```
Projet "Chronique.Android.csproj" (Install cibles) :
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: FFImageLoading.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: Chronique.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: FFImageLoading.Forms.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: FFImageLoading.Transformations.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: Chronique.Android.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: FFImageLoading.Platform.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: FormsViewGroup.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: IF.Lastfm.Core.dll
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: Hqub.MusicBrainz.API.dll

**Configuration:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.8.5
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.8.5+28010.2036
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Version installée : Enterprise

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.11.11-pre (8fb558f)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

Xamarin   4.11.0.776 (d15-8@1ae9b59d7)
Extension Visual Studio permettant de développer pour Xamarin.iOS et Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   4.15.9 (d000f568b)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   1.1.116 (9619170)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   9.0.0.19 (HEAD/a8a3b0ec7)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.0.0.15 (84552a4)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Comment: Turn on diagnostic level debugging for MSBuild, clean/rebuild and post the full AOT build error(s).

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: Well, aot seems to work on my appcenter builds, maybe it is a bug on my local visual studio..

Comment: The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979275/7149454

Answer (score -1):

I was compiling with AOT for my hobby project in my slow home PC, getting the similar errors. I tried all the available work arounds but was not successful. Then I tried the compiling with my latest work computer and it went successful.

So please don't forget try out in faster computer if no work arounds are working for you.